# in/on the construction site

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which is correct?

> (1) Only 100 workers were employed **in** the construction site.
>
> (2) Only 100 workers were employed **on** the construction site.

Comment: _On the site_ is more usual.

Comment: Thank you.   I know usage of prepositions is hard to explain. Does "in" sound awkward there?

Comment: As a general rule we would say someone works *in* an industry, but *on* a site.